# rpm -qa shows package installed but rpm -e says not installed

Tags: rpm, suse, teamviewer

when I run following command

`rpm -qa | grep -i team`

result is:

`teamviewer9-9.0.xxxxx`

but when I do:

`rpm -e teamviewer9-9.0.xxxxx`

it says :

`package teamviewer9-9.0.xxxxx is not installed`

The real problem is that, for some reason teamviewer stopped launching at startup and if I manually type the command `teamviewer` in the terminal, it says command not found, hence wanted to uninstall and re-install.

but before doing that, I don't want to delete the folder in `/opt/teamviewer`, and wanted to understand what is going on? and is there any other way of fixing this issue i.e. reenabling the teamviewer daemon.

the linux distro is:

`(SUSE Linux)`

Comment: you can try `rpm -e teamviewer9` just to make sure there is no typo or similar?

Comment: tried all that but still nothing worked. Finally I ran following: `rpm -Uvh teamviewer9.rpm` (reinstall), and it solved the problem. But question still remains, what exactly was going wrong?

Comment: maybe your rpmdb was corrupt. In that case, you can always run `rpm --rebuilddb`

Comment: ah okay, perhaps! I should have tried that first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe your rpmdb was corrupt. In that case, you can always run

```
rpm --rebuilddb
```